# SCCM service name in pt-br Windows

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-10, windows-server-2012-r2, sccm

I've read that SCCM should be listed in Services.msc as “SMS Agent Host”. But my Windows is localized and there's no service named starting with SMS. There are many starting with Serviço.

I could look on Registry if I knew its internal name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look for the "SMS Agent Host" service display name via the following Powershell cmdlet because the service name will not change in your localized OS.

```
Get-Service -ServiceName 'ccmexec' | fl *
```

[image]